# Swift:関数内で変数の値を更新して、他の関数で使いたい

Tags: swift

Swiftにて以下のようなコードを書いたところ、関数bのprintでは1が出力されるものの、関数aのprintでは0のまま出力されます。
どうすれば関数a内の変数xに関数bでの代入を反映させられるのでしょうか？

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var x = 0

 func a(){
  b()
  print(x)
}

 func b() {
  x = 1
  print(x)
}
```

追記
　説明を端折ってしまい、すみません。
　メソッドa,bは、正確には以下のコードです。

```
@IBAction func a(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {        
    b()
    print(self.id) // 2

    // 画像をNSDataに変換
    let fileName = "image\(self.id).png"
    let pngData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.displayImage.image!)!)
    let file = NCMBFile.fileWithName(fileName, data: pngData) as! NCMBFile

    // ファイルストアへ画像のアップロード
    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // 保存失敗時の処理

        } else {
            // 保存成功時の処理

        }
    })

  }

func b()  {
    // user1クラスを検索するNCMBQueryを作成
    let query = NCMBQuery(className:"xxx")

    // データストアでの検索を行う
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects, error ) in
        if error != nil {
            // 検索に失敗した場合の処理
        }else{
            // 検索に成功した場合の処理
            self.id = objects.count
            print(self.id) //1
        }
    }
}
```

print1ではobjects.countの値が出力されましたが、2でははじめに定義した0がそのまま出力されました。また、アップロードされた画像のナンバリングも、objects.countの値ではなく、0のままでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(前半のコードを残しておいても、あまり多くの人に役立ちそうにないので、ばっさりカットして、**追記**以降の話に絞り込みたいと思います。)

あなたが体験しておられる事象は「非同期処理」に関わるものです。(ここ日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにも関連の質問はすでにたくさん上がっているのですが、検索で見つけ出すのは難しいかもしれません。)

`NCMBQuery`というのはNifty Cloudで用意されているものだそうで、私自身は使った事がないのですが、重要なのは、そのAPIは非同期で実行されるということです。

```
[b()の中にて]

(あなたのアプリ)済んだら、これ`{(objects, error ) in...//1...}`しといてな
(NCMB)よっしゃ(と言って「これ」をどっかに仕舞い込んだら、一旦処理を終了する)

[b()から戻った直後]

(あなたのアプリ)[まだ「済んだら」のタイミングが来る前に`print(self.id) //2`を実行]
-> 検索は終わっていないので、`print(self.id)`は「これ」が実行される前の値
[その後もまだ設定されていない`self.id`を使おうとするが...]

[その後の未来のどこか、いつしか検索が終わった...]

(NCMB)検索が終わったんで「これ」実行しとくわな
-> //1の`print(self.id)`が実行される

[せっかく`self.id`に値を入れたものの誰も使うものがない...]
```

ブレークポイントなどを使わずに、どこの`print(self.id)`が実行されたのかを追っていけば、上記の順番で実行されるのがわかるはずです。(例えば`print("#1",self.id)`,　`print("#2",self.id)`としてみる。)

---

これに対応するためには、どこかのスレッドにあった「delegate内だけで有効な変数を取り扱う」のと同じような発想が求められます。

[1] 完了ハンドラーの中でインスタンス変数に値を設定し、UIの更新などでユーザに伝える

[2] 完了ハンドラーの中でその結果を使うメソッドを呼ぶ

他に、[3] あなたのメソッド用の完了ハンドラーをパラメータとして受け取りそれを(NCMBQueryの)完了ハンドラーの中から呼び出す、という手もあるのですが、1レベル上級になるなので、[2]の方針であなたのコードを書き直してみると、こんな感じになります。

```
@IBAction func a(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    b()
    //b()を呼び出したら何もせずに処理を終了する、完了した時の処理は別メソッドに任せる
}

func b()  {
    // user1クラスを検索するNCMBQueryを作成
    let query = NCMBQuery(className:"xxx")

    // データストアでの検索を行う
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects, error ) in
        if error != nil {
            // 検索に失敗した場合の処理
        }else{
            // 検索に成功した場合の処理
            self.id = objects.count
            print(self.id) //1
            //検索に成功して受け取った値は必ず検索の完了ハンドラーの中で使う
            //処理がやや複雑なら別メソッドにするとわかりやすい
            doSomethingWith(self.id)
        }
    }
}

//`b()`の中で`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`が完了した時に呼ぶ処理は別メソッドに外出しする
func doSomethingWith(id: Int) {
    print(self.id) // 2

    // 画像をNSDataに変換
    let fileName = "image\(id).png"
    let pngData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.displayImage.image!)!)
    let file = NCMBFile.fileWithName(fileName, data: pngData) as! NCMBFile

    // ファイルストアへ画像のアップロード
    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // 保存失敗時の処理
        } else {
            // 保存成功時の処理
        }
    })
}
```

---

私的には非同期処理をうまく使うコツは『済んだら「これ」しといてな』感なのですが、もしかしたらかえって分かりにくくしてしまったかもしれません。お試しいただいて何かあれば、ご質問を編集するかコメントでおしらせください。

Comment: [2]の方法にて、目的の処理を果たすことができました。ご丁寧に本当にありがとうございますm(_ _)m